# Add key to NSDictionary (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, nsdictionary

A really quickly trying to add a key to a .plist. I almost have it, what is the correct version of the fourth line?

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Favourites" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *rootDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [rootDict addKey:@"Test"]; //guessed code
    [rootDict writeToFile:path atomically: YES];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> almost have it

not really.

You can't change a NSDictionary. You can't write to the mainbundle.

---

working code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Favourites" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *rootDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
[rootDict setObject:@"Test" forKey:@"Key"];
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *writablePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Favourites.plist"];
[rootDict writeToFile:writablePath atomically: YES];
[rootDict release];
```

Comment: Hey, good point. On the simulator it lets you write to the mainbundle, thats where I fell into a trap! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 20):

You can't add elements to a NSDictionary, you need to use a NSMutableDictionary then use the `setObject:forKey:` method.

```
[rootDict setObject:someObject forKey:@"someKey"];
```

See [NSMutableDictionary class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Does that create the key ***someKey*** even if it doe not exist?

Comment: It will indeed add the key if it does not already exist - unless your object is nil, in which case it will attempt to remove the key

Comment: Thanks man, worked a dream :) used `setValue:forKey:` though as @fluchtpunkt suggested!